# Save image within bounding box programmatically

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis

I want to save an image from QGIS but the save image functionality feels limited.

Is it possible to use the python command line to save an image at a specific zoomed in scale and to set a bounding box over the region I want to print?

For example, I want to save an image at scale 1:1000 000 within specific coordinates as a bounding box.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try the latest QGis development version ? QGis 3 will feature a much improved "save as image" feature, the version is not yet officially released, but the nightly builds are available and seem quite stable. Presentation of the new feature: http://imhere-asia.com/blog/post/more-qgis-30-improvements-saving-map-canvas-as-image-pdf

Otherwise, you can also use the Composer: add a single map taking all the space, then you can set the scale and coordinates in the properties of the map. Documentation is available here: https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/user_manual/print_composer/overview_composer.html

I am sure it is also possible in Python, but it seems overkill for your usecase.

Answer (score -1):

Exkoria, I know you're using QGIS, but I figured I'd post this code from  ArcMAP in-case you can get some help from it. It pans to each feature in a shapefile and exports an image, and then repeats for all features in the shapefile you specify. Like I said, its not QGIS, but it might help somehow.

```
# This script pans ArcMap, once for each feature in Layer (passed in value)
#
# Note the time.sleep(1), this was included because I needed to pause to
# allow ArcBruTile time to download images. Depending on your mileage,
# this probably needs to be adjusted.
#
# 4/19/2012
#
# http://nodedangles.wordpress.com
#
# 

import sys,arcpy,datetime
inLayer = sys.argv[1]

def printit(inMessage):
    print inMessage
    arcpy.AddMessage(inMessage)

mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")

arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(inLayer, "indexLayer")
cur=arcpy.SearchCursor("indexLayer")

df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]
newExtent = df.extent

iCount = 0
iTotal = (arcpy.GetCount_management("indexLayer").getOutput(0))

for row in cur:
    thisPoly = row.getValue("Shape")
    newExtent.XMin, newExtent.YMin = thisPoly.extent.XMin, thisPoly.extent.YMin
    newExtent.XMax, newExtent.YMax = thisPoly.extent.XMax, thisPoly.extent.YMax
    df.extent = newExtent
    iCount+=1
    arcpy.mapping.ExportToJPEG(mxd, r"C:\scratch\Images\Map_%s.jpg" %(iCount), df,
                  df_export_width=3269,
                              df_export_height=1904,
                  resolution=200,
                              world_file=True) 
#    time.sleep(1)

    printit("Panned to feature {0} of {1}".format(iCount,iTotal))

del row
del cur
```